# Seamless random morphing hex tiles' vertices in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, 3d-meshes, mesh

I have a **hex based, fully flat tilemap** the tiles' mesh currently isn't generated, but a static mesh file containing 6 vertices, UV mapping, etc.

[image]

Then I [saw this picture](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1823506/cant-change-verts-on-mesh-after-assigning-to-meshf.html) on Unity Answers:

[image]

I'd like achieve this. Which is:

- To morph my hexes' vertices **randomly in every direction**
- while they are **all seamlessly still connected**.

(But without having a height for now for simplicity's sake. But that could be a future step.)

So if I move a **vertex0 of Hex A**, the corresponding, **opposing index, vertex3 of the neighbouring Hex B** will move accordingly, like they are all part of one big mesh.

Water tiles would be an exception

- They would be flat: their vertices' Y (up axis) would be constant zero,
- thus I would set every *shore tile*'s water neighbouring borders' vertices' Y to 0 as well. *(now that's an ugly sentence)*

As you can see I have some vague, high level idea about how I would try to achieve parts of this, but code-wise I'm pretty lost. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you already familiar with [the Mesh class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) and how it can be used to create and change geometry at runtime? Another option would be to use a vertex shader which displaces the vertices before rendering based on sampling a noise pattern in world-space.

Comment: I saw some code snippets but nothing more. The shader option could be easy with shader graph I guess. But I'm not familiar with that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myself, I would implement this in the shader.

Use a vertex colour to mark which vertices should be displaced vs. not (so for example, paint all interior land vertices red, and all shore or water vertices black).

Inside the vertex shader, compute the worldspace position of the vertex. Run that position through a noise function like Simplex or Perlin Noise to generate a pseudo-random 2D offset vector. Multiply that vector by the displacement mask stored in the vertex colour (so it gets zero'd out for water vertices), then add it to the vertex position before projecting it to the screen.

This gives you uneven, random-looking warping of the land hexes, without needing tons of unique mesh variants (just one for each combination of water adjacencies). Since the offset vector depends on worldspace position, wherever two vertices coincide at the same position (like two tiles meeting at a shared corner), both vertices will get the same offset, so they'll move as though glued together, even if they're rendered as two completely different meshes with no knowledge of one another. And you'll get the same result frame to frame, so it won't move or animate (unless you want it to).

You can get away with even cheaper, discontinuous noise functions, if your vertices are always *perfectly* positioned to match up, or you do a quick bit of rounding before applying the noise. The continuous noise functions just give you a bit more leeway for small alignment errors to produce only small offset differences (hopefully sub-pixel-sized), and if you're using a shader graph, they're directly available as nodes to use for quick prototyping.

Comment: And I would use 3 different noise textures to sample the x, y, z offsets? If yes, then maybe I have a chance. Except the vertex painting. I have no clue about that :D

Comment: It doesn't need to be a texture at all, but if you do use a texture you can pack x, y, z into a single texture's RGB channels, or sample the same greyscale texture at 3 different positions, either one works. Vertex colours are reasonably straightforward to add — you can find guides for Unity or any 3D content creation tool you like with a quick search.

Comment: The seamless morphing was easy to achieve, thanks! Regarding the vertex painting I'm still searching. Maybe I'll just reuse existing code to set variables in the shader for each hex from a script because it's just one extra line. But it will create new material instances which is bad for performance... I can't find per-instance properties in ShaderGraph to optimize this a bit like in built-in shaders.

Comment: Also another problem for me is that I want to highlight the tiles which I implemented easily because the vertices were fixed. But now they are modified on the GPU. Is there a way to access the new vertex positions? I guess if not my two options are to write a highlight shader... or to ditch the shader solution for the hex morphing all-together. But I once tried implementing a highlight and after hours of trying I gave up. :\

Comment: You can open up your hex mesh using the Mesh class, make copies of it, and set the vertex colours of those copies in script. For matching the highlights, just use the same noise formula in your highlight drawing shader and the two will line up perfectly.

Comment: Oh, I can do that that easily? Thanks! 
My current highlights are just line renderers, I gave up on the shader. I wanted to avoid replicating vertex morph logic at another place but I guess one or two code duplications in the code base isn't that big of a deal.
Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to make it into a custom node that you insert in two places, rather than recreating the whole graph. Or, in shader code, write it as a function in a .cginc file that you import into both other shaders.

Comment: I guess in the long run that's what I'll have to do, thanks for all the help!